# Springboot use inmemory database and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, h2, in-memory-database

I have a SpringBoot application I need to work with two databases. When I use inmemory h2 database it all works fine.
I can access the two databases and read the data.

But I need to acces one MSSQL database and keep the other one in H2 format, for now at least. And here my problems start.
I get the following error when I run my application

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at se.clearon.validoo.JobInvokerController.handle(JobInvokerController.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) [spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:321) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:110) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.initializeConnection(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:447) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:427) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

The SpringBoot application is a batch job, so I thought I should put Spring batch database in the inmemory database, my configuration for spring:

```
spring:
    batch:
        job:
            enabled: false
        initialize-schema: never
        initializer:
            enabled: false
    datasource:
        initialization-mode: never
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer
        username: sa
        password: sa
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
    error:
        whitelabel:
            enabled: false
    profiles:
        active: test
    jpa:
        database: default
```

The other data should be saved to a MSSQL database and my configuration for this looks like this

```
store:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://sql.server:1433;databaseName=store
        username: admin
        password: *****
        validationQuery: "select 1"
```

My configuration class

```
@Profile("!default")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DataSourceConfig {


@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "storeDataSourceProperties")
public DataSourceProperties storeDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "storeDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("store.datasource")
public HikariDataSource storeDataSource(
        @Qualifier("storeDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "storeTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager storeTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("storeDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@Bean(name = "storeJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate storeJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("storeDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
}
```

One of my entities:

```
public class Store {

    private String storeID;
    private String name;

    public Store () {
    }

    public Supplier(String storeID, String name) {
        this.storeID = storeID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStoreID() {
        return storeID;
    }

    public void setStoreID(String storeID) {
        this.gln = storeID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I am not really sure why it is not working?
I should be able to have two databases in SpringBoot right?

I think there is something wrong with my configuration class because I started with two MSSQL databases and that didn't work either.
My use of an inmemory database is only temporarily, but I really need this to work.

Comment: Your `spring.datasource` properties aren't used because you are defining an embedded DB. The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation needs to be on the `DataSourceProperties` bean not on the datasource (else it will use the default config). Also shouldn't the `storeDatasource` be the `@Primary` one?

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum!
I changed first the properties file and commented the datasource for spring. That didn't change anything, I still got the same error.
Then I changed the @ConfigurationProperties like you wrote and now it works!

Sometimes you just need someone to point out the obvious. 

How do I mark your answer as the answer on my question?